# Best way to initialize a temp variable that is used in a loop

Tags: ruby

What is the best way to initialize a temp variable that is used in a loop to keep track of a previous value?

Here is the example of how I would do it but I feel there is a cleaner way. I only want to print the show date if the previous show was on a different day

```
temp_show_date = ""
shows.each do |show|
  if temp_show_date != show.date
    puts show.date
  end
  puts show.name
  temp_show_date = show.date
 end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would probably restructure the data using `group_by` so it more or less matches the desired output. Then you can output the date once, as it becomes the key in a hash, followed by the array of shows for that date:

```
shows.group_by(&:date).each do |date, date_shows|
  puts date
  puts date_shows
end
```

(I'm using IRB's default behavior for supplying arrays as arguments to `puts`, wherein each element is printed on a new line. You can loop through that array if you need to do something else with them).

Comment: This is perfect! Thanks, now I'm seeing why people really love ruby.

Comment: Could you tell me what the '&' does in group_by(&:date) ?

Comment: @wiredin It's a shorthand for [Symbol#to_proc](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Symbol.html#method-i-to_proc). In plain English, it invokes the `date` method on each item in the `shows` collection.

Answer (score 2):

I could write your snipped differently, but answering your question

> best way to initialize a temp variable

would be the `each_with_object`

```
shows.each_with_object("") do |temp_show_date, show|
  if temp_show_date != show.date
    puts show.date
  end
  puts show.name
  temp_show_date = show.date
 end
```

Comment: I guess I asked my question wrong, this is a good way to initialize a variable, but I was also looking for answers where no new variable is necessary. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

So you want to iterate of each group of two consecutive elements. Try [Enumerable#each_cons](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_cons)

```
shows.each_cons(2) do |first_show, second_show|
  if first_show.date != second_show.date
    puts "these two aren't on the same day!"
  end
end
```

Comment: each_cons seems like a very useful method

Answer (score 1):

This shows one approach (using a simple array; you will have to adapt to your particular object type):

```
arr = [1,1,2,1,2,2,3,1]
arr.each_cons(2) do |a,b|
  puts b unless b == a
end
```

Comment: Hi this is something I didn't know I could do, thanks! This could also be a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
shows.each_cons(2) do |s1, s2|
  puts s2.date unless s1.date == s2.date
  puts s2.name
end
```

To print the first one, you can prepare a dummy show  `dummy`, whose date is empty, and use `[dummy, *shows]` instead of `shows`.

Comment: If the first two dates are different (and the first is not ""), OP's code prints both dates. This version only prints the second one.